# "Your npm version is outdated." but it's not. While install yo

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, mean-stack

On Windows 7 64 bit. Installed Node.js via wizard which gave me npm.

I run npm install -g yo and get the following

Your npm version is outdated.

Complete output:

```
C:\Users\dlite922>npm install -g yo
|


> spawn-sync@1.0.11 postinstall C:\Users\dlite922\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\cross-spawn\node_modules\spaw
> node postinstall

C:\Users\dlite922\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\dlite922\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js

> yo@1.4.7 postinstall C:\Users\dlite922\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

√ Global configuration file is valid
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
√ Node.js version
× npm version

Your npm version is outdated.

Upgrade to the latest version by running:
npm install -g npm

See this guide if you're having trouble upgrading:
https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

√ No .bowerrc file in home directory
√ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory

Found potential issues on your machine :(
yo@1.4.7 C:\Users\dlite922\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo
├── titleize@1.0.0
├── array-uniq@1.0.2
├── figures@1.3.5
├── user-home@1.1.1
├── opn@1.0.2
├── async@1.2.1
├── humanize-string@1.0.1 (decamelize@1.0.0)
├── sort-on@1.2.0 (dot-prop@2.1.0)
├── string-length@1.0.0 (strip-ansi@2.0.1)
├── yeoman-character@1.0.1 (supports-color@1.3.1)
├── findup@0.1.5 (commander@2.1.0, colors@0.6.2)
├── meow@3.1.0 (object-assign@2.1.1, minimist@1.1.1, camelcase-keys@1.0.0, indent-string@1.2.1)
├── yosay@1.0.4 (ansi-regex@1.1.1, pad-component@0.0.1, ansi-styles@2.0.1, word-wrap@1.0.3, strip-ansi@2.0.1, minimist@1.1.1, take
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── root-check@1.0.0 (sudo-block@1.2.0, downgrade-root@1.1.0)
├── repeating@1.1.3 (is-finite@1.0.1)
├── configstore@1.0.0 (object-assign@2.1.1, xdg-basedir@1.0.1, osenv@0.1.1, graceful-fs@3.0.8, uuid@2.0.1, mkdirp@0.5.1)
├── update-notifier@0.5.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, latest-version@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.0.0)
├── package-json@1.2.0 (registry-url@3.0.3)
├── got@3.2.0 (lowercase-keys@1.0.0, timed-out@2.0.0, is-stream@1.0.1, prepend-http@1.0.1, object-assign@2.1.1, nested-error-stack
fy@3.4.1)
├── npm-keyword@1.1.1 (registry-url@3.0.3, got@2.9.2)
├── fullname@1.1.0 (npmconf@2.1.2)
├── cross-spawn@0.4.0 (lru-cache@2.6.4, spawn-sync@1.0.11)
├── yeoman-environment@1.2.5 (untildify@2.0.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, log-symbols@1.0.2, diff@1.4.0, text-table@0.2.0, debug@
├── lodash@3.9.3
├── yeoman-doctor@1.4.0 (object-values@1.0.0, log-symbols@1.0.2, each-async@1.1.1, semver@4.3.6, bin-version-check@2.1.0, twig@0.8
├── inquirer@0.8.5 (ansi-regex@1.1.1, cli-width@1.0.1, through@2.3.7, readline2@0.1.1, rx@2.5.3)
└── insight@0.6.0 (object-assign@2.1.1, async@0.9.2, lodash.debounce@3.1.0, os-name@1.0.3, tough-cookie@1.2.0, request@2.57.0)
```

Yet I have a pretty recent npm version:

```
C:\Users\dlite922>npm -v
2.10.1
```

I followed the troubelshooting and put my %appdata% npm BEFORE nodejs in my %PATH% list, but still get the response above.

Any luck?

PS: By the way this mean stack is so disorganized. There's 50 million ways of installing and all advertise a quick two step installation on their frontpage like it's the easiest thing in the world. Then everybody feels stupid when the 20 pre-requisites they assumed was installed does not work. Web App Development future is in shambles if javascript is leading the way these days. I thought PHP days were bad. lol 
/endRant

Comment: File a bug report:  https://github.com/yeoman/doctor/issues  It's probably just not detecting your NPM version correctly.  Also, it does look like `yo` installed correctly, based on that output.  Is it not working?  Finally, you'll have a much better time in the Node.js world if you ignore some of the BS hype that people have tried to add to it.  Node.js and NPM are actually pretty solid systems and things truthfully are easy to install.  But, there are a lot of people out there claiming it's *the* way, and the truth is that everyone's situation is a bit different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `yo` package isn't detecting your `npm` version properly. The output of the installation indicates that it installed correctly.

Comment: Are you basically saying that the error about the yo package failing to detect npm is probably just yo package's fault, and can be ignored?